# Show boot-up details in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

(Go to the last paragraph if you want to skip the background of my question)

I was previously using a corporate modified version of Maverick. After Yosemite is out, I immediately upgraded my OS to the latest ones. However, since I'm upgrading from a corporate modified version, when it's booting up in Yosemite (showing the progress bar), it has 80% of chance to halt at the middle of the progress bar.

I believe that something is wrong; but I got no clue.

I want to ask, during the boot-up in Yosemite, is it possible to see the details when the progress bar progresses?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the details when the progress bar is there. To see details, you can boot in verbose mode, by pressing CMD + V.

Comment: Thx, I've just tried. It seems that by pressing `Cmd + v`, I can see the details before the progress bar; but no detail show up when progress bar presents.

Comment: Not what is meant to happen! It should show the complete boot, maybe Yosemite is odd like that!